# MySQL JOIN 4 different tables

Tags: mysql, join

How to join those 4 different tables so I can get string result instead of numbers. This is my query so far

```
SELECT mg_golub.ID AS IDgolub, mg_golub.brojgoluba, mg_golub.spol, 
       mg_golub.boja, mg_golub.rasa, mg_golub.ime, mg_golub.godina, 
       mg_drzava.drzava, mg_status.status
FROM mg_golub
JOIN mg_drzava 
  ON (mg_drzava.ID=mg_golub.IDdrzava)
JOIN mg_status 
  ON (mg_status.ID=mg_golub.IDstatus)
LEFT JOIN mg_popis_golubova AS Otac 
  ON (Otac.IDotac=mg_golub.ID)
LEFT JOIN mg_popis_golubova AS Majka 
  ON (Majka.IDmajka=mg_golub.ID)
JOIN mg_popis_golubova 
  ON (mg_golub.ID=mg_popis_golubova.IDgolub) 
WHERE mg_popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

I don't know how to link those 3 fields from mg_popis_golbova to mg_golub. I'm stuck with, cause I can't pick data for those 2 columns.

```
LEFT JOIN mg_popis_golubova AS Otac ON (Otac.IDotac=mg_golub.ID)
LEFT JOIN mg_popis_golubova AS Majka ON (Majka.IDmajka=mg_golub.ID)
```

[image]

```
INSERT INTO `mg_golub` (`ID`, `IDkorisnik`, `brojgoluba`, `spol`, `boja`, `rasa`, `ime`, `godina`, `IDdrzava`, `IDstatus`) VALUES
(1, 1, '06557-07-681', 'X', 'kovana', 'Koopman x Schellens', 'Dirk', 2000, 2, 3),
(2, 1, '07216-05-552', 'X', 'kovana', 'Koopman', 'Tata', 2001, 2, 3),
(3, 1, '2081-01-271', 'Y', 'kovana', 'Schellens', 'Die Weischwantaubi', 2003, 2, 3);

INSERT INTO `mg_popis_golubova` (`ID`, `IDkorisnik`, `IDgolub`, `IDmajka`, `IDotac`) VALUES
(28, 1, 1, 3, 2),
(27, 1, 3, 0, 0),
(26, 1, 2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: "normal" string result? what's an abnormal string result?

Comment: I'd _really_ love an autoindent function on this site... :-/

Comment: replace those numbers with string

Comment: Could you explain the relation between the 3 fields on mg_popis_golubova and mg_golub ?

Comment: IDgolub is pigeon, IDotac is its father and IDmajka is its mother and they have unique numbers that is brojgoluba. and I need to pick them all to echo them

Comment: Is the format of `brojgoluba` the fields separated by dashes, ie `IDgolub-IDmajka-IDotac`?

Comment: no, it should be separate variable.
As you can see they are bond to ID in table mg_golub and using that bond I need to get value from column brojgoluba

Comment: @FosAvance I can't see how they're bonded. Could you give an example of a row in mg_popis_golubova and a row in mg_golub that should match, and why? I don't see IDgolub/IDmajka/IDotac in mg_golub to match on.

Comment: IDgolub/IDmajka/IDotac match ID to mg_golub
maybe this helps http://i.imgur.com/bxa2VP6.gif

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT mg_golub.ID AS IDgolub, mg_golub.brojgoluba, mg_golub.spol, 
       mg_golub.boja, mg_golub.rasa, mg_golub.ime, mg_golub.godina, 
       mg_drzava.drzava, mg_status.status
FROM mg_golub
JOIN mg_drzava 
  ON (mg_drzava.ID=mg_golub.IDdrzava)
JOIN mg_status 
  ON (mg_status.ID=mg_golub.IDstatus)
JOIN mg_popis_golubova 
  ON (mg_golub.ID=mg_popis_golubova.IDgolub) 
WHERE mg_popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

Comment: I know that, but problem is that this query doesn't pick data for all 3 colums "IDgolub", "IDmajka" and "IDotac", it just picks data for "IDgolub"

Comment: you are not selecting them

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean to add the tables data

Comment: would there be any differences?

Comment: I guess I'm ignorant, I don't know how to do it

Comment: just select them and paste them in your question

Comment: Done. I need solution just for table mg_golub and mg_popis_golubova, for other 2 is easy

Comment: I need this as result, I can get everything but those last "Majka" and "Otac" column
http://i.imgur.com/bxa2VP6.gif

Comment: sorry i dont understand anything what you want. you dont show what result you need. i mean edit your question and put wished result in table .

Comment: No, please edit your question to explain, instead of opening a new question.  Duplicate questions just create confusion.