# JOIN 3 columns from 1st table to one column from 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I need query that will give me this result. 
[image]

Here are my 3 tables. Columns `IDgolub`, `IDmajka` and `IDotac` from `mg_popis_golubova` refers to ID from `mg_golub`. 
Column `IDstatus` from `mg_popis_golubova` refers to ID from `mg_status`.

[image]

This is my query that I'm using to accomplish this. But it is not working. Because it merge nly column `IDgolub` from `mg_popis_golubova` and column `ID` from `mg_golub`. What about  `IDgolub`, `IDmajka`. How to merge those two columns to `ID` to get results.

```
SELECT 
mg_golub.ID AS IDgolub, mg_golub.brojgoluba, mg_golub.spol, mg_golub.boja, mg_golub.rasa, mg_golub.ime, mg_golub.godina, mg_status.status
FROM mg_golub
JOIN mg_status ON (mg_status.ID=mg_golub.IDstatus)
JOIN mg_popis_golubova ON (mg_golub.ID=mg_popis_golubova.IDgolub) 
WHERE mg_popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

Comment: Please don't open the same question ([MySQL JOIN 4 different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717613/mysql-join-4-different-tables)) multiple times - instead, try to improve the existing question.

Comment: I tried but people didn't understand so I made a new one with new explanation

Comment: This is not about joining four tables, its about joining two tables, one on a compound value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for. You need to join the `mg_golub` table multiple times to get the results you're looking for, which means you need to use table aliases.

```
SELECT 
    mg_golub.ID AS IDgolub, mg_golub.brojgoluba, mg_golub.spol, mg_golub.boja, 
    mg_golub.rasa, mg_golub.ime, mg_golub.godina, mg_status.status, 
    otac.brojgoluba, majka.brojgoluba
FROM mg_golub g
JOIN mg_status s ON (s.ID=g.IDstatus)
JOIN mg_popis_golubova pg ON (g.ID=pg.IDgolub)
JOIN mg_golub otac on (pg.IDotac = otac.ID)
JOIN mg_golub majka on (pg.IDmajka = majka.ID)
WHERE mg_popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

I'm not familiar with the language your table and column names are in, so I'm sure you can come up with much better aliases that I have.

Comment: This is final and correct answer, I just needed to modify it a little bit. Thank you very very much:D